# How do I create a 2 dimensional array from a text file in Android?

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

How can make a two dimensional `Array` of integers by reading from a .txt file that looks like this:

```
0000                
0100            
1233
```

Would you use `BufferedReader` or `InputStream`?
Here is what I have so far and it either crashes, or it just says 52, 52, 52....

```
 public static void loadTileMap(String fileName, int height, int width) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(GameMainActivity.assets.open(fileName)));
    String line;
    tileArray = new int[width][height];
    while (true) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            reader.close();
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            String string = line.toString();
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if (j < string.length()) {
                    int k = (int)string.charAt(j);
                    tileArray[i][j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Reader is something different than a Stream. To create a BufferedReader you'll need an InputStream. Just google for "android read file line by line" and you'll find a sollution really quick.

Comment: **2**D? Where is **2**D, in your example? I can only see a **1**D vector.

Comment: it would be a 2d array like this  
[[0000], [0100], [1233]]

Comment: No. I think it would be a **1**D array, like this: `[0000, 0100, 1233]`.

Comment: No but im telling you it wouldnt and im pretty sure i know what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK thank you for all your help! I did what CyberGeek.exe suggested but I modified it a bit. Here is my code:

```
public static int[][] tileArray;

public static void loadTileMap(String fileName, int height, int width) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(GameMainActivity.assets.open(fileName)));
        String line;
        tileArray = new int[width][height];

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                reader.close();
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int k = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(j, j+1));
                tileArray[i][j] = k;
            }
        }
}
```

There might be an easier way but I'm not sure. Either way this works for me!

Comment: This should lead to an array look me this though; [[0,0,0,0][0,1,0,0][1,2,3,3]]

Comment: ya... thats what i said, a 2d array of ints

Answer (score 1):

Bufferdreader. Also to make a 2D array like that the steps should look like this:

1 - make the 2D array

2 - as you read watch line add it to the array[line#][0]

Also, you are converting the char into an int. Thereby causing it to change to its Unicode (or ASCII I don't know) representation e.g. 52.

Comment: oh that makes sense but i tried and im not sure how to get an int instead of a char. It wont let me do string.charAt(j).getNumericalValue

Comment: If you want an array like the one in the comment above you can just use int x = Integer.parseInt(string). And add it to array[I][0]

Comment: ok that seems to work better but could you please post an example of the whole method? when i do it things keep messing up. It keeps putting it as only 3 numbers instead of 3 arrays of the numbers.